# Solving an equation algebraicly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Just wondering, how can ALL the answers be found to the equation:

$2^\pi+\pi=2^n + n$

Obviously $\pi$ is a real solution, but how can I get this result;

and can I obtain other solutions?

Comment: Show the function is strictly increasing so therefore there can only be one solution

Comment: Is there a complex element to this question, or are we restricted to the real numbers?

Comment: abiessu has already asked my question: what if there is a complex solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we wish to find a complex solution $n=a+bi$ to

$$2^\pi+\pi=2^n+n=\exp((a+bi)\ln 2)+a+bi$$

Separating real and complex parts is the best approach, so we have

$$\exp(a\ln 2)\exp(bi\ln 2)=\exp(a\ln 2)(\cos(b\ln 2)+i\sin(b\ln 2))\\
2^\pi+\pi-a-\exp(a\ln 2)\cos(b\ln 2)=0\\
i\exp(a\ln 2)\sin(b\ln 2)+bi=0$$

One solution appears to be at $n\approx 3.536373+7.971928i$, as found by using a graphing calculator.  Here's a zoomed-out version to see some of the solutions:

[image: x+yi]

Comment: oh how can I missed such a striaghtforward method... anyways, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a question about real numbers.  If not then disregard this. Let $f(x)=2^x+x$.  Then $f'(x)=\ln(2)2^x+1$.  Thus $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.  Thus $f$ is strictly increasing.  So it can only take any given value once.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Define $F(n)=2^n + n  - (2^\pi + \pi).$    Then $F'(n)=2^n \ln 2 + 1.$  Is $F'(n)$ ever negative?